# Reset redis info statistics

Tags: redis

I want to reset the statistics redis shows me in `INFO` command.
I read about https://redis.io/commands/config-resetstat

But for some reason it returns error:

```
redis> CONFIG RESETSTAT
ERR unknown command `CONFIG`, with args beginning with: `RESETSTAT`,
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't want to restart server, since I use digitalocean and I don't have direct SSH access, I have only access to redis-cli.

Comment: That means the command has been disabled by the admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@for_stack is right, i want to expand the answer. It is not possible to use `config` command unless you/administrator modify the configuration file which requires a server access and restart.

How they [disabled](https://redis.io/topics/security#disabling-of-specific-commands)?

The `CONFIG` command was renamed into an unguessable name.

> `rename-command CONFIG b840fc02d524045429941cc15f59e41cb7be6c52`

It is also possible to completely disable it (or any other command) by renaming it to the empty string.

> `rename-command CONFIG ""`

You need to request your administrator(if it is possible) to remove that lines from the configuration file.

Comment: Ahh exactly, I remember this security thing. Thank you

Comment: @Victor could you please approve if it is solved on your side, it may be helpful for someone later. Best

Comment: Yep, I upvoted but forgot to approve it since I couldn't do this immediately. Done